# ObjC casting a block with toll-free-bridged types

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, toll-free-bridging

Is it possible to pass a block that takes Objective-C types which have Toll-free-bridged equivalents directly into a method expecting a block with the C-types?

**Concrete example**

I'm wrapping the AddressBook and Contacts APIs depending on availability, and the frameworks contain two methods that for all intents and purposes are identical.  Consider the completion block parameter of:

`CNContactStore`'s `- (void)requestAccessForEntityType:(CNEntityType)entityType completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL granted, NSError *error))completionHandler`

and

`AddressBook`'s `void ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion ( ABAddressBookRef addressBook, void(^)(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) completion );`

I have a block of type `void (^)(BOOL granted, NSError *error)` and it would be great if I could pass it to `ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(...)`.  I know that I could wrap my 'objc' block inside a block which takes the 'C types' as parameters but it feels pointless to do so when the types are toll-free bridgable.

**Concrete questions**

Is there a way to cast an object of type `void (^)(BOOL granted, NSError *error` to type `void(^)(bool granted, CFErrorRef error)`?  If we can, what is the syntax?  What are the implications of ownership in an ARC environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply cast the block.

As a very rough example:

```
typedef void(^InternalBlock)(bool granted, CFErrorRef error);

- (void)requestAccess:(void (^)(BOOL, NSError *))completion {

    if ([CNContactStore class]) {
        [contactStore requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:completion];
    } else {
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, (InternalBlock)completion);
    }

}
```

Comment: I never even considered doing a non-bridging cast as I'm scared about the underlying memory management.  "What are the implications of ownership in an ARC environment?" Am I overcomplicating the issue.  I guess all blocks are ObjC objects (read: id) regardless of whether it contains C or ObjC types so memory management doesn't matter.